# Problem with installing pytorch with pip3: -f option requires 1 argument

Tags: linux, pip, pytorch, torch

I am trying to install torch in linux with cuda version 11.1
I checked this: Start Locally | PyTorch
It says that the code is

```
pip3 install --user torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f
```

However, this line gives this error

```
-f option requires 1 argument
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must have missed `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`
use the below cmd

```
pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cu102 torchvision==0.10.0+cu102 torchaudio===0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 3):

While looking at the Pytorch installation instructions, it looks like you are missing a link after -f

According to https://pytorch.org/, The pip command would be

```
pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

You are missing the https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html and thus are getting the error

Sarthak